# failed to find PDF header: `%PDF' not found

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, pdf, xcode6

I get this log when i try to load a pdf and don't know why.

```
failed to find PDF header: `%PDF' not found.
```

hers my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{


    [webview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://webdesign-schoenefeld.de/es-app/heute.pdf"]]];
    NSLog(@"---------------pdfloading....,------------------------");
    [webview addSubview:activityind];
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(1.0/2.0)
                                             target:self
                                           selector:@selector(loading)
                                           userInfo:nil
                                            repeats:YES];
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}
```

I use Xcode 6 Beta 5 and iOS 8 beta 5.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Yes . I am facing problem like you said. Have you found any solutions or this is bug?

Comment: Yes. I am also getting this problem. Has anyone solved this one or raised it to apple as a bug?

Comment: This worked for me in iOS 8 beta 3, but not in iOS 8 beta 5, in beta 5 I have to use loadData instead of loadRequest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update on SEP 9 2014: iOS8 GM fixed this issue for apps I'm working with.

Response prior to SEP 9 2014
It is reported as a known bug by Apple in iOS8 Beta 5 release notes.
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-8.0/
https://devforums.apple.com/message/1017919#1017919

We should wait next release and see if it is fixed.

Comment: It's not fixed in Beta 6.

Comment: @Keenan, iOS8 Beta 6 didn't ship yet. Xcode beta6 did ship.

Comment: @BorisSuvorov,
Rumors say that iOS8 Beta 6 was distributed to carries around Aug 19

Comment: The release notes say that it is a known issue for Quicklook, does this apply to `UIWebView` too?

Comment: @user454322 I haven't tested specifically in UIWebView, but i know it's a problem for quicklook, yes.

Comment: @Keenan Thanks for the follow up. Same error message is displayed with   `UIWebView` and this question seems to be about `UIWebView`.

Answer (score 10):

I agree, there seems to be a bug (or change of behaviour) in iOS 8 beta 5 which means that your code does not work anymore (and it was valid. I have the same and it worked fine up to iOS 8 beta 4).

I think there is a problem with type detection because if I do the following, it works:

```
NSLog(@"About to request PDF document loading...");
NSData *pdfData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlStr]];
[self.webView loadData:pdfData MIMEType:@"application/pdf" textEncodingName:@"utf-8" baseURL:nil];
```

Now that bit of code should not be used "as is" as it is synchronous.

I feel Nithin's answer was valid but it does not answer the problem specifically seen with iOS 8 beta 5. The main code is the same and will hit the same iOS bug.

Comment: I have the exact same problem in Swift since IOS 8 Beta 5. My workaround is downloading the file asynchronously and then use your code ported into swift for displaying it in the webview. Then it's working. Hope they're going to fix that problem in the next beta..

Comment: Yes, using loadData works, while loadRequest doesn't. Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me

```
NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:pdfFilePath]; // <pdfFilePath> if full path of your pdf file
NSData *pdfData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:targetURL];
[self.webview loadData:pdfData MIMEType:@"application/pdf" textEncodingName:@"utf-8" baseURL:nil];
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem in iOS 8 beta 5.
The code like https://stackoverflow.com/a/25302602/2639006 works, but I would recommend to add last baseURL param, because internal pdf document links doesn't work without it.

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"pdf_NAME"ofType:@"pdf"];
NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
NSData *pdfData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:targetURL];
[self.webView loadData:pdfData MIMEType:@"application/pdf" textEncodingName:@"UTF-8" baseURL:targetURL];
```

Answer (score 1):

I have been beating myself up over this particular problem for years, and finally found the answer today. I've always found that some PDFs open fine in iOS (either with code like yours that tries to load it in a `UIWebview` or by using UIApplications's canOpenUrl: method) but others can't be opened at all.

Basically, the PDF needs to have a header/footer set in order to be openable by iOS (technically it's actually just Safari that has this problem, as Quicklook and Acrobat Reader can handle header-less PDFs on the devics with no problem).

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue building an app off the iOS 8 SDK and Xcode 6. My issue was that NSXMLParser was calling the foundCharacters method twice on my selected tag. I figured this out by checking if my string data was a multiple of 4 so that I could even attempt to convert it to a base 64 encoded data object. Once I found out that the method was called twice, I figured that concatenating the strings together would produce the correct data:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string {

    if([self.currentElement isEqualToString:kWarrantyPDFXMLTagDocumentData]) {

        if (self.combinedDocumentString == nil || self.combinedDocumentString.length == 0) {
            self.combinedDocumentString = string;
        }
        else {
            self.combinedDocumentString = [self.combinedDocumentString stringByAppendingString:string];
        }

        if (![self stringIsBase64:self.combinedDocumentString]) {
            return;
        }
        pdfData = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:[NSData base64DataFromString:self.combinedDocumentString]];

        // If you want to save your PDF, do so here.
        NSString *documentsDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)[0];
        NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.pdf"];
        [pdfData writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
    }
}



- (BOOL)stringIsBase64:(NSString *)str {
    if ([str length] % 4 == 0) {
        static NSCharacterSet *invertedBase64CharacterSet = nil;
        if (invertedBase64CharacterSet == nil) {
            invertedBase64CharacterSet = [[NSCharacterSet
                                        characterSetWithCharactersInString:
                                        @"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+/="]
                                       invertedSet];
        }
        return [str rangeOfCharacterFromSet:invertedBase64CharacterSet
                                 options:NSLiteralSearch].location == NSNotFound;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this error message when sending a PDF document I generated to the printer (at least in the simulator).  Got around it by adding a title to the PDF document by supplying a CFDictionary instead of nil as the last parameter to building the pdf context.  Here is Swift 3.0 help:

```
    let infoDict : CFDictionary = [kCGPDFContextTitle as String : "myTitleHere"] as CFDictionary  // Add title to PDF

    let pdfData = NSMutableData()
    if let dataConsumer : CGDataConsumer = CGDataConsumer(data: pdfData) {
        let myMediaBox = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: page.pageWidth, height: page.pageHeight)
        if let pdfContext = CGContext(consumer: dataConsumer, mediaBox: &myMediaBox, infoDict) {
            // .... more pdf stuff
        }
    }
```