# failed to find PDF header: `%PDF' not found iOS, PDFKit

Tags: ios, swift, ios11, pdfkit

I'm downloading a `pdf` and show it to to the end user using `PDFKit`. most of the time it works properly. for some cases, it gives me an error called

> **failed to find PDF header: `%PDF' not found**

I went through several readings and StackOverflow questions like [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25158552/failed-to-find-pdf-header-pdf-not-found). but still didn't figure out the solution to outcome of this problem. in some articles, it says it is a bug from Apple. isn't it fixed it yet?

here is how I'm downloading the pdf

```
    let destination: DownloadRequest.DownloadFileDestination = { _, _ in
        let documentsURl = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
        let fileurl = documentsURl.appendingPathComponent(mydocumentname + ".pdf")
        return (fileurl, [.removePreviousFile, .createIntermediateDirectories])
    }

    Alamofire.download(urlrequest!, to: destination).responseData { (response) in
        switch response.result {
        case .success( _):
            completion(response.destinationURL)
        case .failure(let err):
        }
    }
```

this works fine in most cases. but fail in some cases with the above error. does anyone know a solution for this? hope your help with this. have a nice day.